# Send HttpClient request without DefaultRequestHeaders

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I'm working with a poorly designed API, and among its flaws, it has one particular endpoint that should not be give a particular custom header, while literally every other endpoint requires it. As a result, it's included in `DefaultRequestHeaders`, so I don't need to add it manually to every request.

However, now, for this one particular endpoint, I need to remove it, and I'm not sure how or if it's even possible. Complicating matters somewhat, I'm dealing with a singleton-scoped `HttpClient` instance, so any fudging around with `DefaultRequestHeaders` is a no-go. In other words, I can't do something hacky like temporarily remove the header and then add it back in after the request, because that might affect other concurrent requests being made. Frustatingly, even if I drop down to using `SendAsync` with a custom `HttpRequestMessage` instance, `HttpClient` *still* adds the header.

Also, while it would work, I'd really prefer not to have to inject *another*  `HttpClient` instance without the header added to `DefaultRequestHeaders`. Working with two different `HttpClient` instances within the same class just seems like a hugely bad idea for many reasons.

Am I out of luck here, or is there some solution I've missed after scouring the Interwebs for the past hour?

**UPDATE**

One thing I did find what that with a custom `HttpRequestMessage` instance, I can essentially clear the header by setting it to an empty string on the `HttpRequestMessage`. Since it's then explicitly set, `HttpClient` does not overwrite it with the default version. That still means the header is being sent, but at least it doesn't actually have a value. Still interested in a better solution, though, if one exists.

Answer (score 5):

You can do that inside handler `SendAsync` override, because at this point `HttpClient` has already added default headers to your request. If you are not using custom handler - you can inherit from `HttpClientHandler` and use that, because `new HttpClient()` is the same as `new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler())`. For example:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    HttpClient c = new HttpClient(new MyHttpClientHandler());
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Test", "1");
    var res = c.GetAsync("http://google.com").Result;
}

class MyHttpClientHandler : HttpClientHandler {
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        // check for your endpoint
        if (request.RequestUri.Host == "google.com") {
            // remove
            request.Headers.Remove("X-Test");
        }

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you're looking for, but if you don't want to send the header on *every* call, I wouldn't use `DefaultRequestHeaders` for it at all. To me it feels like less of a hack to add it "manually" when you need it, rather than removing it for one endpoint.

Of course you want to keep it DRY. Without seeing your code, assuming you're making all calls to the API from a single class, one possibility would be to just create a private helper method like this that all other methods defer to:

```
HttpRequestMessage BuildRequestMessage(object body, bool sendCustomHeader = true)
```

Or, maybe a helper that also takes a verb and endpoint and actually sends the request.

Alternatively, if you want to keep this "noise" out of the main API wrapper class, you could create a handler like in @Evk's answer, except there again I would skip using `DefaultRequestHeaders` and flip the logic to *include* the header if you're *not* calling the specific endpoint.